# Value returned by Oracle PL/SQL function is not printed out

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote a PL/SQL function that updates salary by employee id and returns stopwatch as INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND.

When called, it updates salary but I also want it to print out the stopwatch value. How can it be achieved? I've tried adding this line `dbms_output.put_line(stopwatch);` but the function still just updates salary and doesn't print out the stopwatch value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function myfunction1(e_empno_in IN NUMBER, e_sal_in IN NUMBER)

RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
IS 
e_empno emp.empno%TYPE := e_empno_in;
e_sal emp.sal%TYPE := e_sal_in;

thestart TIMESTAMP;
stopwatch INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;

BEGIN
    SELECT current_timestamp INTO thestart FROM dual;
    UPDATE emp SET sal = e_sal WHERE empno = e_empno;
    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
        raise_application_error (-10001, 'No row found for id ' || e_empno);
    END IF;
    SELECT current_timestamp-thestart INTO stopwatch FROM dual;
RETURN stopwatch;
dbms_output.put_line(stopwatch); --> *trying to print out stopwatch value*

END;
```

Calling the function:

```
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(myfunction1(7654, 2559));
END;
```

Comment: Unless I'm way off, it ends at the RETURN.  Put the put_line call before the return.

Comment: Are you running this from SQL*Plus?  If so, you might need to set terminal output on... plus what @Twelfth said.

Comment: Yes, the `dbms_output` line is unreachable. If you had PL/SQL warnings enabled you would have got `PLW-06002: Unreachable code`.

Comment: The code looks OK to me, what I don't see an `EXCEPTION` block, which would catch a possible error. Replace the line `dbms_output.put_line(stopwatch);` with `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN dbms_output.put_line('Error' || SQLCODE); and run it again. I'm suspecting that the update doesn't happen. +++ Use `raise_application_error ( -20001, ' No row found for id ' || e_empno);`, as -10001 is not user reserved number for raising application errors !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` before the `RETURN` statement.
You also don't need to use SQL to get the current time (it can be done in PL/SQL) and you don't need to reassign the input parameters to use them as bind variables.

```
CREATE function myfunction1(
  e_empno_in IN emp.empno%TYPE,
  e_sal_in   IN emp.sal%TYPE
)
RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
IS 
  thestart  TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  stopwatch INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
BEGIN
  UPDATE emp
  SET   sal   = e_sal_in
  WHERE empno = e_empno_in;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
      raise_application_error (-10001, 'No row found for id ' || e_empno_in );
  END IF;

  stopwatch := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - thestart;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stopwatch);

  RETURN stopwatch;
END;
/
```

Comment: With this solution, the next question (to the OP) is, "why is this a function and not a procedure"? What is being done with the return value, other than displaying it to the screen?

Comment: Btw, even having an unreachable code at `dbms_output.put_line(stopwatch);`, the function is still called within a `dbms_output`, which should output the `stopwatch` value.

Comment: @MT0 I'm probably missing something.. I've edited the function according to your suggestion. but after I run the following statement `BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(myfunction1(5555, 7787));
END;` the salary value updates in the table but `stopwatch` value is not printed out.